# How to delete a Test app in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps) read:

[image]

It looks like it is not true. There is no any *Test Apps tab* in my production app dashboard. And FB doesn't bother to provide screenshots or any path to it.

Does anybody know where it can be deleted?

Comment: I can't find it either, but do you really *need* to delete it? What harm is it doing?

Comment: @ceejayoz: No harm. I wanted to make some screenshots for my non-dev colleague on how to create apps and test apps in FB. Now I want to delete a test app which I don't need. I have one test app I use now, and don't need another.

Answer (score 5):

I found out how.

It is definitely not *in the Test Apps tab of your production app* as FB claims.

1. Go to your test app you want to delete. It is in your prod app dashboard.

[image]

2. Select **Settings -> Advanced**. It is in your test app now you want to delete.

[image]

3. At the bottom of the page there is a red button.

[image]